# Pact Test fail with initializationError in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, maven

I really don't know why we are using PactTest in spring boot test cases .But when i run my below PactTest class i am getting below Error why i am facing this issue and please help me to resolve this issue.

### Class

```
@RunWith(PactRunner.class)
@Provider("OrderMs")
@PactFolder("target/pacts")
@VerificationReports({"console", "markdown"})
public class VerifyPacts {

    private static ConfigurableApplicationContext application;

    @TestTarget
    public final Target target = new HttpTarget(8080);

    @BeforeClass
    public static void startSpring(){
        SystemPropertiesLoader.addSystemProperties();
        application = SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    /*
     * Initializes the default values for the provider services
     */
    @State({"default", "extra"})
    public void toDefaultState() {
        System.out.println("Now service in default state");
    }

    @State("extra")
    public void toExtraState() {
        System.out.println("Now service in extra state");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void kill(){
        application.stop();
    }
}
```

### Error trace

```
java.lang.Exception: Did not find any pact files for provider OrderMs
    at org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError.<init>(InitializationError.java:38)
    at au.com.dius.pact.provider.junit.PactRunner.<init>(PactRunner.kt:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be a bit late for a reply, but just in case... and for others that may run into this question.
The Pact annotation "@PactFolder" by default looks in the  of the project.  So, in order for this test to work, you would need to do the following:

1. Make sure you have a "target/pacts" directory, where a "contract" exists.  A "contract" is a JSON file containing what are called "interactions" which are pairs of "requests/responses" that would normally take place between a consumer (i.e. a UI/micro-client, or another micro-service) and a provider (i.e. normally another micro-service).
2. See the example below, in your case the **provider** must match "OrderMs"

Example:

```
{
  "consumer": {
    "name": "<consumer-name>"
  },
  "provider": {
    "name": "**OrderMs**"
  },
  "interactions": [  
        <Your interactions>  
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "pactSpecification": {
      "version": "2.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE**: This implementation is not ideal; you should really make use of a PACT-BROKER in to publish your contracts.  That way they stay current and your provider is always validating the most current version.